# How to write conditions in a SQL stored procedure?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I've got this stored procedure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[GetSessionInfo]') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSessionInfo]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSessionInfo](
    @SessionID int)

WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT [cfgGroup].[Name] as GroupName,[cfgSession].[Name],[cfgSession].[GroupId],[cfgSession].[IsDisabled],
    [cfgSession].[IsTestSession],[cfgSession].[NextExecutionTime],[cfgSession].[SType],[cfgSession].[DaysToKeep],
    [cfgSchedule].[ID],[cfgSchedule].[SessionId],[cfgSchedule].[MinuteFreq],[cfgSchedule].[HourFreq],
    [cfgSchedule].[Daily],[cfgSchedule].[WeekFreq],[cfgSchedule].[StartDate],[cfgSchedule].[EndDate],
    [cfgSchedule].[NoOrderDays],[cfgSchedule].[OrderDays],[cfgData].[ID],[cfgData].[SessionId],[cfgData].[StationExclude],
    [cfgData].[StationFilter],[cfgData].[ConsoleExclude],[cfgData].[ConsoleFilter],[cfgData].[MedClassesExclude],[cfgData].[MedClassesFilter],[cfgData].[PickAreasExclude],
    [cfgData].[PickAreasFilter], [cfgData].[DeviceType]
    
    FROM [cfgGroup],[cfgSession],[cfgSchedule],[cfgData]
    
    WHERE [cfgGroup].[ID] = [cfgSession].[GroupId]
    
    AND
    [cfgSession].[ID] = @SessionID
    
    AND
    [cfgSchedule].[SessionId] = [cfgSession].[ID]
    
    AND
    [cfgData].[SessionId] = [cfgSchedule].[SessionId]

END
GO
```

I need to change what data the stored procedure returns based on what is in `[cfgSession].[SType]`

`[cfgSession].[SType]` can only be `Send` or `Receive`

If `[cfgSession].[SType]` is `Send` then I need it to return what is currently in the `SELECT` statement above.

If `[cfgSession].[SType]` is `Receive` then I need it to return what is currently in the `SELECT` above minus the `[cfgData]` fields.

Comment: Is there some reason to believe that only one value of `[cfgSession].[SType]` will be returned? Given no DDL or sample data we're just guessing. Asides: You might want to come into the 21st century and stop using ANSI style joins. It's so last millennium. It's unusual to have a stored procedure return recordsets that don't have a consistent set of columns. Would an `outer join` and empty columns suffice?

Comment: @HABO this is a super old script that is causing a bug in our application. I normally don't do the back end stuff but was asked to try and fix it. If you were to fix it how would you do it?

Comment: First I'd get agreement for a suitable hourly rate. Then I'd ask the client for access to the database and sufficient rights to be able to examine the DDL and data. Ideally there would also be access to the source code for the application so that I could determine what is causing the mismatch and address it appropriately.